# PHP file upload works only with 777 permission folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form that send some files to a php script.
I had set

file_uploads = On

in the php.ini file.

It works when I set the upload folder for 777 permission.
But does not work with neither 775 nor 776.

Could someone give me some light?

Thank you very much.

P.S.: if is need, that is my scrip:

```
if (isset($_FILES['groupImage' . $i])) {
foreach ($_FILES['groupImage' . $i]['name'] as $f => $name) {     
    if ($_FILES['groupImage' . $i]['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }          
    if ($_FILES['groupImage' . $i]['error'][$f] == 0) {            
        if ($_FILES['groupImage' . $i]['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
            $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["groupImage" . $i]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . $property_id . "_" . $count . "." . pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) {
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<input name="groupImage1[]" type="file" id="inputFiles" multiple>
```

Comment: What owner/group is the folder, and what owner/group is your webserver running as?

Comment: I am sorry, I am really sorry, how can a know the owner/group of the webserver?

Comment: Typically there will be something in the webserver configuration to say what user/group it should be running as, or monitoring the actual webserver process should tell you as well

Comment: Oh I see, thank you.
The server owner/group is:  root:root
And my is: thiago:thiago   (my username)

Actually, I am developing in LAMP, in my machine, when I upload for the server (I don't have it yet) will the owner/group of the user be the same of the owner/group of the server?
I am sorry for ask a so fundamental question, I am very beginer.